# Why does .hover() not work on mapped images, but .mouseover() does?

Tags: jquery, html, image, imagemap

Recently was working with image maps and trying to do something on hover of an image map. Naturally I tried `.hover()` first, but that didn't work and so when I tried `.mouseover()` that worked.

My question is, why does one work and not the other?

```
/*This function works*/
$(document).on('mouseover', '#some-map', function(){
    console.log('I am hovering with mouseover()');
}).on('mouseout', function(){
    console.log('I am no longer hovering with mouseover()');
});

/*This function does not work*/
$(document).on('hover', '#some-map', function(){
    console.log('This is from hover()');
}, function(){
    consoel.log('Out from hover()');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there ar no on('hover' ... method in jquery you can write it like this

```
$('#some-map').hover(function(){
   alert('This is from hover()');
}, function(){
   alert('Out from hover()');
});
```

Comment: Ahh, okay. That makes sense then. So how would I create a hover event for a dynamically created element?

Comment: i always used to write like this:
<button>Click</button>

<script>
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('body').append("<h1 id='some-map'>hello world</h1>");
  $('#some-map').hover(function(){
    alert('This is from hover()');
  }, function(){
    alert('Out from hover()');
  });
})